# no definition Keys c#

Tags: c#, key

```
foreach (string myKey in mySortedList.Keys)
```

why it says does not contain definition Keys and no extension Keys. may i know why? i already `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: Doesn't look like `mySortedList` is actually `SortedList<>` - what is it, then?

Answer (score 2):

whatever `mySortedList` actually is, it has no property `Keys`.  The compiler told you that much.  So:

1. Determine the type of `mySortedList`.
2. Go to MSDN, consult documentation.
3. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

Either `mySortedList` is not a `SortedList` or it hasn't been un-boxed from it's more primitive state.

```
var list = mySortedList as SortedList;

foreach (string myKey in list.Keys) { ... }
```

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: there is nothing to do with the sorted implementation. is the Keys the one that cause the problem. even im doing other code for example take the key for List<int> using the Keys, still displays it does not contain definition of Keys..please please help me. is there anything to do with my library?how to solve this?

Comment: what is the ***original*** type of `mySortedList`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an example will help. In the code below, the first foreach compiles, but the second doesn't. Both are based on the same instance of a SortedList, but the second one casts it as a different type, which does not support Keys.

```
        SortedList<string, string> sorted = new SortedList<string, string>();

        foreach (string s in sorted.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        IEnumerable stillSorted = sorted as IEnumerable;

        foreaach (string t in stillSorted.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine(t);
```

Is this your problem? If you are being passed an object, try casting it yourself as in the example below:

```
        SortedList<string, string> sorted = mySortedList as SortedList<string, string>;
        if (sorted != null)
            foreach (string s in sorted.Keys)
                Console.WriteLine(s);
```